# ¿Cómo saber la versión de GX antes de abrir una kb?

Tags: genexus

Tengo varias versiones de GX con diferentes upgrades instaladas en mi PC. Por otra parte, tengo varias KB generadas en distintas versiones.

Actualmente llevo un registro manual para saber en que versión de GX abrir cada KB. Sucede que al abrir una kb (generada en una version en particular).  Para realizar "un pequeño cambio" Si es abierta con una versión diferente a la que fue generada: se importan componentes, actualizan módulos, etc y al hacer un build o rebuild all se generan muchos errores. El resultado es que ese "pequeño cambio" termina siendo una tortura.

¿Existe una forma sencilla de saber en que versión de GX abrir una kb? ¿O se puede saber (a priori y antes de abrirla) con que versión y upgrade fue abierta por última vez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la versión no queda visible en los .cs/.java a menos que prendas la propiedad del Generador: "Expose descriptive metadata". Ahi se van a generar los archivos con un comment al principio con esa informacion.

Si esa propiedad está en "No" (que es el valor default) la unica vuelta que tenes es ver el numero de build en el archivo ".ver" del directorio web, por ejemplo:

```
En.NET Core: "GNetCoreB160130.VER"

En .NET Framework: "GNetWebB158949.VER"
```

El nombre del archivo contiene el número de build

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias! Cual sería la forma mas sencilla de a partir de un nro. de build saber la version de GX y upgrade. En el Download Center?

Comment: Si, ahi figuran los nros de build por version